# Unable to import CSS with "babel-plugin-react-css-modules" - get "ParseError: Unexpected token"

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, css-modules, babelify, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

Please see https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/issues/162 for full description of issue.

Git repo = https://github.com/basher/react-no-webpack

This is a simple POC / scaffold for a React UI lib **without Webpack or Gulp** but it must support **CSS Modules + Sass**.

- I'm just trying to use Babel + Browserify.
- And executing NPM scripts directly from "package.json".

I have a sample widget component that imports a CSS file, and another that imports a Sass file. The error happens when parsing the content of both CSS + Sass files - e.g. transpiler does not understand "." in the class selector.

Here's the specific error:

```
$ npm run watch

> react-no-webpack@1.0.0 watch C:\...path-to-project-folder...\react-no-webpack
> watchify ./src/index.js -o ./build/bundle.js -t babelify -v


C:\...path-to-project-folder...\react-no-webpack\src\lib\components\WidgetCSS\WidgetCSS.css:1
.widget {
^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

**Edit / Update:**

I've done some more investigation, and have asked a question in **react-css-modules** repo too = https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/issues/268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParseError: Unexpected token` mean your babel not understand css syntax

`react-css-modules` module need transpiler css like `webpack`, read for [more detail](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#browserify).

For your case you can use [`css-modulesify`](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modulesify).

**1) Install css modulesify**

`$ npm install --save css-modulesify`

**2) Update your package json script**

```
"build": "browserify ./src/index.js -p [ css-modulesify -o ./build/main.css ] -o ./build/bundle.js -t babelify",
"watch": "watchify ./src/index.js -p [ css-modulesify -o ./build/main.css ] -o ./build/bundle.js -t babelify -v"
```

remember to include `./build/main.css` to `index.html` for css.

Comment: Thanks @hendrathings

2 comments about your answer:

1. **babel-plugin-react-css-modules** claims to work without Webpack, and with browserify. This is why I'm seeking help as there is quite clearly an issue with this actually working as expected.

2. **css-modulesify** is highly experimental and has not been updated for 8 months. I've chosen to ignore this package.

Comment: @basherkev `react-css-module` need 2 setup either webpack or browserfy. Please check https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#browserify for detail. It's says, if use browserfy refer to css-modulesify.

Comment: also, `babel-plugin-react-css-modules claims to work without Webpack` where is you find this? The docs use webpack, check here: https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#installation. If you see the demo, it is using webpack.

Comment: There is no way without `webpack` or `css-modulesify`. It will throw error `ParseError: Unexpected token` because javascript trying parse `css` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @hendrathings - you are correct.

I must have misread the docs, or read about a non-webpack setup somewhere else. I've read so many articles recently that I have probably confused myself!

I have followed your suggestion - I'm now using **css-modulesify**.

I have a working example POC UI lib with minimal React + CSS Modules config, with both CSS and Sass syntax (using a couple of example PostCSS plugins). This can be found in my updated https://github.com/basher/react-no-webpack repo.